# How do get PE 64 executable for cygwin?

Tags: windows, operating-system, cygwin, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I want to compile a program for 64 bit operations. So I have a couple of doubts here:
1. Do I need the executable file to be PE 64?
2. If yes, how do I compile a 64 bit executable on cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a 64bit cygwin program, install the 64bit version of cygwin

https://www.cygwin.com/
https://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe

The exe formats for 32bit and 64bit are:

```
$ file /bin/bash.exe
/bin/bash.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows

$ file /bin/bash.exe
/bin/bash.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```